# RMSE of a multi-output regression model (using sklearn mean_squared_error)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

I tried two ways in getting the RMSE of my multi-output regression model:

```
# method 1
mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred, squared = False)
```

AND

```
# method 2
math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred))
```

However, these two do not give the same value. Which would give the correct/reasonable answer? How does each method compute the RMSE?

I am getting near but unequal values for different test sets:

Test Set 1

> method 1 RMSE - 0.0016348880777322008 method 2 RMSE -
> 0.001758368311904257

Test Set 2

> method 1 RMSE - 0.0010033910901866248 method 2 RMSE -
> 0.0010335145033944881

Comment: This cannot be the actual code you're running. In the second example, if you have `squared=False` then the end result would be a square root of RMSE and numbers will be entirely different

Comment: Edit: Yes, this is not the code I used. There is no `squared = False` in method 2. Thanks for the comment. I overlooked the code I posted earlier. My question still remains.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what your issue is if you don't provide examples of data causing such behaviour. I can confirm in my testing that the values are the same:

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from math import sqrt
import numpy as np

true = [1.1, 1.2, 2.4, 3.1, 4.7]
test = [1.3, 0.9, 2.5, 3.3, 4.5]

rmse = mean_squared_error(true, test, squared=False)
rmse_other = sqrt(mean_squared_error(true, test, squared=True))

print(f'RMSE: {rmse}, RMSE_sqrt: {rmse_other}')
print(f'Are they equal within standard tolerance?  {np.isclose(rmse, rmse_other)}')

Out:
RMSE: 0.20976176963403026, RMSE_sqrt: 0.20976176963403026
Are they equal within standard tolerance?  True
```

Comment: Please try `y_true = [[0.5, 1],[-1, 1],[7, -6]]` and `y_pred = [[0, 2],[-1, 2],[8, -5]]` (examples from https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error.html). Based on my manual calculations, method 1 calculates the RMSE by computing the RMSE per column first then gets the average of all RMSE values per column, while method 2 gets the MSE of each element, averages all MSE values, then takes the square root of the overall average. What are your thoughts about this?